# How to call Excel macro with parameters from Powerbuilder

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this line of code to call a macro from Powerbuilder.

```
ole_1.object.application.Run("CreateChart")
```

And this is working fine.Now i want to call a macro that takes arguments.How can i do that?

Comment: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm